# Convert empty arrays from JSON to XML with Json.NET (Newtonsoft)

Tags: c#, json, .net, xml, json.net

Given the following JSON:

```
string json = @"
  {
    ""Identifier"": ""MyID"",
    ""Data"": []
  }";
```

If I convert it to XML with: `XDocument xDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "Foo");` then the resulting XML is:

```
  <Foo>
    <Identifier>MyID</Identifier>
  </Foo>
```

My desired output is something like:

```
  <Foo>
    <Identifier>MyID</Identifier>
    <Data/>
  </Foo>
```

Is there a serializer setting or something I can use to make this change?

EDIT: For clarity - I am looking for a general solution without knowing the structure of the JSON ahead of time. The goal is to simply convert arbitrary JSON to XML without omitting tags for empty arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/578) would be the reason to the behaviour you see. It seems to come down to how xml represents arrays: nodes just get repeated

```
void Main()
{
    JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(@" {""Identifier"": ""MyID"", ""Data"": [1,2,3]}", "Foo", true, false);
    /*
        <Foo>
          <Identifier>MyID</Identifier>
          <Data>1</Data>
          <Data>2</Data>
          <Data>3</Data>
        </Foo>
    */
    JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(@" {""Identifier"": ""MyID"", ""Data"": [null]}", "Foo", true, false); // this seems to be the closest to what you are after, but it is semantically different from empty array
    /*
    <Foo>
      <Identifier>MyID</Identifier>
      <Data json:Array="true" xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json" />
    </Foo>
    */
    JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(@" {""Identifier"": ""MyID"", ""Data"": []}", "Foo", true, false);
    /*
    <Foo>
      <Identifier>MyID</Identifier>
    </Foo>
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example assumes that you have a form named Form1 (Form1.cs).

Give the following a try:

**Install Newtonsoft NuGet package**

- On menu, **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**
- In Solution Explorer,right-click <project name>
- Select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Click **Browse**
- Search: Newtonsoft.Json
- Click **Newtonsoft.Json**
- Click **Install**

Create a class named Foo

**Foo.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace NewtonsoftEmptyXmlElement
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Foo")]
    public class Foo
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "Identifier")]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }

        [XmlArrayAttribute("Data")]
        public List<string> Data { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

**Add the following using statements:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

**GenerateXml** (returns XML as a string)

```
public static string GenerateXml<T>(object obj, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
{
    string xml = string.Empty;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        //eliminate "xsd" and "xsi" namespaces
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        //indent Xml and eliminate Xml declaration
        XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        writerSettings.Encoding = encoding;
        writerSettings.Indent = true;


        //create instance of XmlWriter
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, writerSettings);

        serializer.Serialize(writer, (T)obj, ns);
       
        xml = encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());

    }

    return xml;
}
```

**WriteXML** (write XML to file)

```
public static void WriteXml<T>(object obj, string filename, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
{
    string xml = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            //eliminate "xsd" and "xsi" namespaces
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");

            //indent Xml and eliminate Xml declaration
            XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            writerSettings.Encoding = encoding;
            writerSettings.Indent = true;


            //create instance of XmlWriter
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, writerSettings);

            serializer.Serialize(writer, (T)obj, ns);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: - " + ex.Message);
    }
    
}
```

**Test**

```
private void Test()
{
    string json = @"
    {
        ""Identifier"": ""MyID"",
        ""Data"": []
    }";

    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);
    Foo foo2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include });

    //Option 1 - get XML
    string xmlDoc = GenerateXml<Foo>(foo2, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); 
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\n" + xmlDoc);

    //Option 2 - write XML to file
    WriteXml<Foo>(foo2, @"C:\Temp\foo.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

**To use:**

```
Test();
```

**Output:**

```
<Foo>
  <Identifier>MyID</Identifier>
  <Data />
</Foo>
```

Comment: Please see edited question. This solution would require me to create a class for the JSON.